# iOS: Make the PDF view same size as the device width height

Tags: ios, pdf, orientation, uipageviewcontroller, autoresizingmask

There is grey colour in background and I cannot make full size of the PDF. Is there a way to make full screen of the PDF? I have detected the orientation and made the pdf size accordingly.

Edited:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"PDF2" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *pdfUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
PDFDocument = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)pdfUrl);
totalPages = (int)CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(PDFDocument);
//modelArray holds the page numbers
modelArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int index = 1; index <= totalPages; index++) {

    [modelArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", index]];

}

thePageViewController = [[UIPageViewController alloc]
                         initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl
                           navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal
                                         options:nil];

thePageViewController.delegate = self;
thePageViewController.dataSource = self;

thePageViewController.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

contentViewController = [[ContentViewController alloc] initWithPDF:PDFDocument];
contentViewController.page = [modelArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:contentViewController];
[thePageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

[self addChildViewController:thePageViewController];
[self.view addSubview:thePageViewController.view];
thePageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

[thePageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor underPageBackgroundColor];
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: are you creating your own pdf or you are just displaying PDF file? how you are showing pdf file? plz put some code

Comment: for displaying, are you using UIWebView or else?

Comment: It is a view controller